# Pull a data from db where each array holds the column name category and its subinfo

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting, pull

I am trying to create an accordion menu where each accordion menu pulls the rutines of workouts where it differs by the category column in the db example below;
[image: Accordian menu that the db informations manually put]

I got my PDO::db design like this;

id
title
describtion
category
hashtags
video
seen
date_published

how can i pull the info from the database by the category to use it in foreach in my view file. I hope i could make my problem clear enough.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could order by category and then name (*make sure you have an index on category, name*)
Your Query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `workouts` ORDER BY category, name
```

Then when you iterate you check if the category changed and if, close the sublist and open a new one showing the category first.

Another, slightly cleaner Solution would be to iterate twice, using the first loop to sort in an associative array by category:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM workouts");
$sth->execute();

$workouts = array();
/* First Loop */
while(($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) {
    $workouts[$result['category']][] = $result; 
}
```

Now you can loop over $workouts, using the key as the Category.

```
foreach($workouts as $category => $workoutsByCategory) {
  //display category and start subset
  foreach($workoutsByCategory as $workout) {
    //display workout
  }
}
```

It would be a lot cleaner thou to use a second table which holds the category names and use the id of that table in your workouts table to connect. You can then get the results using join. You might want to look into Relational Database Design and [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Example (not tested) Table Layouts:

```
table "workouts"
id | category_id | title | description | hashtags | video | seen | date_published
table "categories"
id | title
```

Then you can get the results using:

```
SELECT workouts.*, categories.title as category_title FROM workouts LEFT JOIN categories ON (category.id = workouts.category_id)
```

This will make it easier to change the name of a category amongst other advances ... but you'll read up on that i guess.

Comment: I am so freaking suprised to express my feelings right now. Your answer has given me the exact structure to accomplish it right away!

Comment: Thank you for the appreciation! Do read up on Relational Database Design thou. 
It will improve your work and your own work experience. It will leave you even more surprised i guess :D